# Controlar em uma aplicação em segundo plano com applescript

Tags: script, apple

Olá, nesse exemplo abaixo funciona, ele abre a aplicação Skype e digita "email" e aguarda 20s para a próxima ordem, porem eu gostaria que ele fizesse isso sem que abrisse o app, sem a parte do "activate" executasse em segundo plano:

```
tell application "System Events"
    delay 3
    repeat
        tell application "Skype"
            activate
        end tell
        delay 0.3
        keystroke "email"
        delay 20
    end repeat
end tell
```

é possivel?